# Make SUMO vehicules re enter scenario to make it last longer

Tags: ns2, sumo

Im working with a Vanet scenario in Ns2 and SUMO but Im having some problems with the simulation because all the vehicules leave the scenario really fast and I want them to be inside the scenario during the whole simulation time, how can I make the SUMO scenario work like that if Im using a segment from an osm file.

Comment: You could increase the x y settings in the simulation.tcl: `set opt(x) 3000` ...  `set opt(y) 3000` ... (Or 2000 / 2000 ?)

Comment: I understand that&#39;s the size of the grid but what I want is to be able to have different car numbers in an scenario rotating during the whole simulation time or define a different number of cars to test how different car densities affects traffic simulation when importing the sumo mobility to ns2 nodes but I can't find a way to make the cars stay in the scenario the whole simulation time and declare different numbers of cars for each simulation

Comment: Did you read this one http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_maintain_a_constant_number_of_vehicles_in_the_net.3F ?

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the information I see they have an example of what I want, a circularscenario but it wont let me download it in fact the link is down do you have that example, this is the link but it does not show anything http://sumo.dlr.de/trac.wsgi/browser/trunk/sumo/tests/sumo/cf_model/drive_in_circles/circle

Comment: I fixed the link in the wiki.

Comment: ok I created the .cfg file and manage to test that scenario but it is to big i have built an scenario .net file, is it posible to have 50 cars running for 1000s in that scenario,the problem is that I dont know how to make the cars last for the whole simulation im stuck, this is my .net file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kkZREvEucz-J28_0zu_aibV2oBGlU6Ij